# block decorated letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i need to block decorated letters like

this is my code

```
             if ( $name != htmlspecialchars($name) )
         {
              $this->err[0] = register_player_txt_invalidchar;
         }
```

Comment: Are those letters special UTF characters or just an HTML element with styles?

Comment: Rather than account for every special character, wouldn't it be easiest to check for allowed characters?  Do you only allow letters/numbers?

Comment: i only need  letters/numbers/spaces

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to detect unicode characters via the `htmlspecialchars()` function.  There's actually an entire library for dealing with unicode and other multibyte-encoding characters in PHP.  Take a look at the [Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

You may want to try something like this:

```
if ( strlen($name) != mb_strlen($name) )
{
    $this->err[0] = register_player_txt_invalidchar;
}
```